# How to bind tmux key #?

Tags: tmux

I am unable to bind the `#` key to a tmux command. I have tried

```
bind \# command-prompt -p "create vert pane from (put window-number[.pane-number]): " "join-pane -sv ':%%'"
bind # command-prompt -p "create vert pane from (put window-number[.pane-number]): " "join-pane -sv ':%%'"
```

It interprets the `#` character as a comment in the tmux.conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `#`, you need to use quotes; the backslash escaping only really works for the semicolon.

Also, your `join-pane` command probably need `-vs` instead of `-sv`; otherwise the `-s` option will take `v` as its argument leaving the prompted value as an unsupported argument to the command itself.

```
bind '#' command-prompt -p "create vert pane from (put window-number[.pane-number]): " "join-pane -vs ':%%'"
```

Either double or single quotes should work.