# What is the command I can enter in the tmux command bar to show the pane numbers?

Tags: tmux

I would like to bind `#` to show panes numbers because `#` means number. I found out how to bind `#` [from this question](https://superuser.com/questions/567976/how-to-bind-tmux-key) but what's the `tmux` command for showing panes. I tried `show pane-numbers` from the [docs](https://tmuxguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tmux/tmux.html)  because I thought it was a command because a hyphen was included in the description but it turns out that it is just that, a description, and nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "docs" you linked to is not the official documentation. It looks like a guide that deviates from the tmux standard in the very beginning:

> The command ‘ctrl-b’ is replaced with ‘crtl-a’ along with some other changes.

Note in this answer I assume the default configuration. In particular I assume the prefix is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.

The real documentation is here: [`tmux(1)` manual page](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1).

The phrase "pane numbers" appears after <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> as:

> ```
> C-b q       Display pane numbers
> ```

but to know the tmux command for this (without studying the documentation thoroughly) you need to examine the output of `list-keys`:

```
tmux list-keys | grep prefix | grep q
```

The output is:

```
…
bind-key    -T prefix       q                    display-panes
```

This way you can learn the tmux command you seek is [`display-panes`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#displayp). You can verify what it does by running the following command in a shell inside tmux:

```
tmux display-panes
```